# docker multiple stages - docker gradle build success but docker openjdk failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i am trying to build jar files in docker gradle, then docker openjdk copy the jar files and run it.

but hitting error

```
Step 10/14 : COPY --from=builder /test-command/build/libs/*.jar /app/test-command.jar
ERROR: Service 'test-command' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

docker file

```html
FROM gradle:5.6.3-jdk8 as builder

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /test-command
ADD --chown=gradle . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN gradle build 

FROM ubuntu
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

WORKDIR /app
VOLUME ["/app"]
COPY --from=builder /test-command/build/libs/*.jar /app/test-command.jar
COPY --from=builder /test-command/docker/startup.sh /app/startup.sh
#RUN sh -c 'touch /app/test-command.jar'
RUN chmod +x /app/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/test-command.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

when the docker gradle building files, i can view them by using below docker command, and i saw the path, jar files in the container.

but once build is completed, then i did not see the container anymore.

could it be the reason why docker oepnjdk cannot find the files / source path??

```
docker exec -it name-of-container bash
```

Comment: I'm a little comfused that you change working directory to `/app` and run `gradle build`, but in another stage, you copy jar from `/test-command`. Is this a mistake, or gradle will put the output artifacts into `/test-command`?

Comment: Also in this Dockerfile you have an empty `FROM ubuntu` image, and a `VOLUME` that will prevent some or all of the actual runtime container setup from happening (definitely the `RUN chmod` commands will have no effect).

Comment: Finally i make it works. I'll edit main post about it. Thanks.